# Ошибки при просмотре расширений VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

При поиске расширения по названию выдаётся список. Пытаюсь кликнуть на любое, чтобы посмотреть - вкладка открывается и закрывается мгновенно, выдавая ошибку. Вот что выводится в инструменты разработчика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переустановка редактора ничего не дала. Ранее все работало, успешно просматраивал расширения и устанавливал их. Помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что ваш DNS сервер не может разрешить доменное имя, к которому подключается VS code.

Попробуйте сменить используемый DNS сервер. [Например на Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#change_your_dns_servers_settings).

Comment: Вы правы, спасибо. Еще обнаружил, что не имею доступа к некоторым сайтам по той же причине. Сейчас все работает.